# AWS: Associate already assigned Elastic IP to a new instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp, elastic-ip

I have an EC2 instance with one `Elastic IP` associated to it. I want to check if I can assign this IP to a new instance which I create?

Something like:

`Disassociate the IP --> associate a new instance`

Is this possible? Any alternate way to do this?

**Reason to do this**: I have firewall issues in corp network which does not allow me to connect to the instance. I have to raise a whitelisting request to network team and then I do the RDP. I'll be having multiple instance created and I don't want to raise a new request each time.

Comment: Have you thought about creating a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance for this purpose?  It's potentially somewhat different than the normal use case for those things, but would allow you to access that resource from any instance in your VPC because they'd all have the same source address.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that from AWS console and also using SDK/APIs. When you disassociate the elastic IP:

- The instance you dissociated may lose internet access if the subnet has "Auto Assign IP" option disabled
- The instance you dissociated will get a new public IP (not elastic) if the subnet has "Auto Assign IP" option enabled.

Alternative:

- Allocate a new elastic IP (if you are within the limit) and assign the new IP to your new instance

Comment: There's one relevant "gotcha" with EIPs when used in a VPC in an account where EC2-Classic is still enabled for the region (even if not actually being used) -- unless "allow reassociation" is specified when the address is associated with an instance, it can't be migrated without stopping the instance.  Apparently, VPC-Only accounts (all accounts created after 2013-12-04, and older accounts where you have asked AWS Support to disable/remove EC2-Classic) don't exhibit the same behavior.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#VPC_EIP_EC2_Differences

Answer (score 1):

Amazon offers the ability to allocate an Elastic IP address. An Elastic IP provides you a single IP address that you can associate with different EC2 instances over time. If your EC2 instance has an Elastic IP and that instance is ever stopped or terminated, you can immediately associate a new EC2 instance with the Elastic IP. Your existing applications will not break because the applications see the IP address they were expecting, even though the back-end EC2 instance has changed.

To allocate an Elastic IP and associate it with an Amazon Web Services (AWS) instance, do the following:

1. Open the AWS Management Console, click the EC2 link, and display the page associated with your region.
2. Click the Elastic IPs link in the EC2 Dashboard.
3. Click Allocate New Address and choose VPC or EC2 from the drop-down list, depending whether you're going to associate this IP with an instance in Amazon EC2-Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) or Amazon EC2-Classic, respectively. Click Yes, Allocate to confirm your choice.
4. Right-click the newly created Elastic IP and choose Associate Address.
5. Choose your desired EC2 instance from the drop-down list of running instances and click Associate.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for your use case, it would be a better option to set up a NAT Gateway and point it to the Default Gateway route in the routing table so that you get the flexibility to use any EC2 instance, within the VPC Subnet to access your Corporate Network.

`Your EC2 instance (Within VPC with any IP) --> NAT Gateway (With Elastic IP) --> Corporate Network`

This way your Corporate Network sees the NAT Gateway IP as the inbound IP address.

Coming back to your original question, Yes it is possible to disassociate it and associate it again and back to a new EC2 instance simply using the AWS web console.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can Disassociate the Elastic IP and associate with a new instance.

If you are using the AWS console, make sure to enable **Reassociation** when associating the address so that you don't have to do the extra step **Disassociate** to re-associate with a new instance. If you haven't enabled it, you can always re-associate by first disassociating and then associating EIP with an instance without the need to shutdown any.

Or you can simply do a nested RDP. You can RDP into any instance from an instance within your VPC unless you have restricted access to them.